# QGIS Alter Elevation Values in DEM

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation

How do I add 1.77 to all **negative** elevation values to increase an overall water depth by 1.77m in a DEM please, i.e. what is the script I would use in the raster calculator?

Comment: Do you mean *subtract* 1.77 from negative elevations?  If your elevation is -2.0m (i.e. water depth is 2m) then adding 1.77m to that will result in an elevation of -0.23m.

Answer (score 1):

the expression in the raster calculator would be:

```
("elevation@1" < 0) * "elevation@1" + 1.77
```

where elevation is your DEM raster layer

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to **add** the depth of a water body by 1.77 meters so that a body of water body with a depth of -1m will be -2.77m after the calculation.

Using QGIS version >=3.22 (because https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html#feature-add-if-function-to-raster-calculator)

You can use the `IF` statement in the raster calculator, `if (condition, true, false)` where the true statement will be calculated if the condition is fulfilled and vice versa.

```
if ("elevation@1" < 0, "elevation@1" - 1.77, "elevation@1")
```